# Zend Form Element Select - 'Select One' Message

Tags: forms, zend-framework, validation

I have a form element (see below).  This works great but the default selected option is 'Red'.  How do I make the default option some message like, 'Choose' but also make validation fail if the 'Choose' option is submitted?

```
        $this->addElement('select', 'colors', array(
            'label' => 'Choose a color:',
            'multiOptions' => array(
                1 => 'Red',
                2 => 'Green',
                3 => 'Blue',
                4 => 'Purple',
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (tested)

```
$this->addElement('select', 'colors', array(
    'label'        => 'Choose a color:',
    'required'     => true,
    'multiOptions' => array(
        null => 'Choose'
        1    => 'Red',
        2    => 'Green',
        3    => 'Blue',
        4    => 'Purple'
    )
));
```